# Uncaught Error: No module: ui.bootstrap.alert in angular.min.js line 17

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

Here is my html and angular js code

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular App</title>
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui-bootstrap-custom-0.4.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.4.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap.alert']);
        function AlertDemoCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.alerts = [
    { type: 'error', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' },
    { type: 'success', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' }
  ];

            $scope.addAlert = function () {
                $scope.alerts.push({ msg: "Another alert!" });
            };

            $scope.closeAlert = function (index) {
                $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
            };

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
        <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
        <button class='btn' ng-click="addAlert()">
            Add Alert</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The angular UI bootstrap alert is not working and in the console its throwing error

```
Uncaught Error: No module: ui.bootstrap.alert  in angular.min.js line 17
```

Comment: What is inside your custom UI file?

Comment: that is the custom bootstrap ui build from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/  for alert

Comment: I'd try to inject ui.bootstrap instead of ui.bootstrap.alert

Comment: i'm new to angular ...how to do that.??

Comment: instead of writing var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap.alert']);

you would do:

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

But nvm, that shouldn't be the issue, i was false

Answer (score 0):

Same issue ... this is the error.
SCRIPT5022: No module: ui.bootstrap 
angular.min.js, line 17 character 443

I am actually injecting dependency on ui.bootstrap - not on alert.
Another interesting observation - this issue is showing up only for IE (Chrome and Firefox are quite happy) !!!

Any pointer would be great ....

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, a silly answer really.  I'd downloaded the file ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js frmo github by right-clicking and saving.  This didn't work, instead of downloading the .js file, the html file that it pointed to was downloaded.

Make sure that you ui-bootstrap-*.js file looks like the file here:

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js

You should also ensure that your ui-bootstrap-*.js is loaded *before* your app.js (or where ever you declare your angular modules).